# Filtering Look up Columns with Javascript

Tags: 2013, javascript, lookup-column, filter, url

I'm trying to find a way to dynamically filter a look up column on the new and edit forms in SharePoint 2013.

I want to be able to get a value from the URL and use that to filter the look up choices. Something like, only show choices where "column A" equals "Value from URL"

Has anyone ever done this? or know of any references i can use? I do not want to filter the choices based on another column which seems to be the common question people ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding what i needed with SPServices. I used the filter drop down function, Code below.

http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPFilterDropdown

```
$().SPServices.SPFilterDropdown({
         relationshipList: "{*List ID*}",
         relationshipListColumn: "*column Name*",
         columnName: "*Column Nam*e",
         CAMLQuery: "**CAML QUERY**",
         completefunc: null,
         debug: true 
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Since CSR is the *default rendering mode* in SharePoint 2013, I would recommend the following approach to manipulate form fields in `New/Edit` Form page. As an introductory please follow this article [Introduction to Client Side Rendering in SharePoint 2013](http://www.rbradbrook.co.uk/Blog/Post/10/Introduction-to-Client-Side-Rendering-in-SharePoint-2013).

Suppose a Tasks list that contains a `Task Category` lookup field. Then the following rendering template could be used for setting `TaskCategory` lookup field value retrieved from a query string parameter named `cat`:

```
(function () {
    var ctx = {};
    ctx.Templates = {};
    ctx.Templates.Fields = {
        'TaskCategory': {
            'NewForm': renderTaskCategory
        }
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctx);
})();


function renderTaskCategory(ctx) {
    var catId = GetUrlKeyValue('cat'); //extract cat parameter from a query string 
    ctx.CurrentFieldValue =  catId; //set lookup field value 
    return SPFieldLookup_Edit(ctx); //default template for rendering Lookup field control
}
```

### How to apply changes

In order to apply the changes we need to set the `JSLink` property of XLV web part:

- First of all, let's save this JS template and name it `Tasks.js`. Then upload the specified into SharePoint `Site Assets` library
- open New Form page in Edit mode and go to web part properties
- find under `Miscellaneous` group `JSLink` property and specify its value:
  `~sitecollection/SiteAssets/Task.js` as shown on figure below
  [image]

### Result

[image]

**Parse query string in SharePoint 2013**

SharePoint JS Library contains `GetUrlKeyValue` function for extracting query string parameter, for example:

```
var itemId = GetUrlKeyValue('ID'); //get Item Id from query string
```

Comment: +1, Indeed a better way of doing this.

Comment: Looks great, I'll give it a shot this week and mark as answered if it works for me.

Comment: looking through this with a little more detail, I'm not seeing a way to do a query to filter the look up field. I'd like to apply a filter probably using CAML based off the URL. Not just set the value based off the URL.

Answer (score 0):

The Jquery code below reads the query string value and prepopulates the lookup field.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        JSRequest.EnsureSetup();
        var dropDownValue = JSRequest.QueryString['AccountReference'];
        if (dropDownValue) {
            $("select[title='External Client Account']").children("option").each(function () {
                if ($(this).text() == dropDownValue) {
                    $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Source: http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2014/10/sharepoint-pre-populate-lookup-field-in.html