# Document Library - Lookup Column Filter

Tags: sharepoint-server, lookup-column, filter, document, library

I have metadata tags utilized in my document library - several of them are lookup columns.  One of these lookup columns is to a list named "Projects".  This list also has several other columns - "Start Date, End Date and Status".
When users edit metadata in my document library, I would like the drop-down of the Projects lookup column to be filtered to only show projects from that list whose status is open based on "End Date".
For lists I can work InfoPath to filter Lookup field drop-downs. **** But ***** in document libraries not afforded this option in InfoPath to filter the lookup columns -- thus in my projects lookup in document libraries -the drop-down is a large list.
-- Is there a way with script or query to filter the dropdown in the metadata edit form in a library?

Comment: I am confused by what you are trying to implement. Do you want at document upload time to validate the Project lookup value and show only Open projects in selection DDL?

Comment: Are you using SharePoint online or some version of on-prem?

Comment: See if this gets you what you need:  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/125999/filtering-look-up-columns-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can create a column "status" as Progects list in the current document library, and use JavaScript to create cascading dropdown as the article provide below. Then select the status in the document library form and it will display the relevant project.

Reference:[Tool Level Cascading Drop Down in SharePoint 2013 using SPServices](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/758909/Two-Level-Cascading-Drop-Down-in-SharePoint-using)